# android econnreset on http connection

Tags: android, econnreset

So I have been trying everything under the sun to stop this error. The app works fine but it it like it times out and then moves on, which makes it take forever. I have googled this, and searched on here for about a week, and noone seems to have a good answer as to why or how to fix this issue. I use a dedicated server to upload the data to.

Connect.java

```
public class CallLog extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{       
        @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() 
       {
           super.onPreExecute();   
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(String result)
       {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
       }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {                       
            try
            {                   
                String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";


                Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriCalls, null, null, null, strOrder);

                if(cur.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        // GET CALL INFORMATION
                        String callID = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID));
                        String callNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                        String callName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                        long callDate = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                        String callType = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
                        String isCallNew = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW));
                        String duration = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                        String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm").format(callDate);

                        // POST TO WEBSITE
                        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");         
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new
                                   HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com");

                           nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);

                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_id", callID));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_number", callNumber));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_name", callName));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_date", formattedDate));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_type", callType));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_duration", duration));
                           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call_isnew", isCallNew));

                           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));
                           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                           is = entity.getContent();

                    }
                    while(cur.moveToNext());

                    if (is != null)
                    { 
                        is.close(); 
                    }
                }

                cur.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            //error.setText("Connection error");
           }
            return null;
       }
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

stacktrace:

```
06-03 12:09:08.941: W/System.err(16271): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
06-03 12:09:08.951: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
06-03 12:09:08.951: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at com.trackit.TrackRec$SMSReceive.doInBackground(TrackRec.java:140)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at com.trackit.TrackRec$SMSReceive.doInBackground(TrackRec.java:1)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-03 12:09:08.956: W/System.err(16271): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
06-03 12:09:08.961: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
06-03 12:09:08.961: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:140)
06-03 12:09:08.961: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
06-03 12:09:08.961: W/System.err(16271):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
06-03 12:09:08.961: W/System.err(16271):    ... 24 more
06-03 12:09:08.961: E/log_tag(16271): Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

Comment: The ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) generally means a server error/failure processing the request (Post in your case) . Can you debug/log the server side?

Comment: Let me google how to do that and after I find out I will post the results.